# How to write more then one method inside one servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am working on ajax for getting data from my server as back-end i am using java-servlets

Now what issues i am facing is:

- i have to call two data for two different work via ajax
- So what i am doing currently is creating two servlet class and making two ajax call to both of them
- i am writing all my codes in `doGet` method of one servlet
- and via ajax call in `url` i am giving servlet class name

**What i am trying to do**

- can't i create one servlet and inside it i can make several methods and make ajax call on that servlet class method

**what i am doing**

Servlet1 code

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String categoryCode, categoryName, quantity,sql,str = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();     
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> lhm = null;
    LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>> mainList = new LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>>();
    try {

        sql = "1";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            categoryCode = "A101";
            categoryName = "drinks";
            lhm.put("Category Code", categoryCode);
            lhm.put("Category Name", categoryName);
            mainList.add(lhm);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(str);

    }}
```

Servlet2 code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String itemName, itemCode, quantity,sql,str = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();     
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> lhm = null;
    LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>> mainList = new LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>>();
    try {

        sql = "2";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            itemName = "pepsi";
            itemCode = "AA00";
            lhm.put("Item Code", itemCode);
            lhm.put("Item Name", itemName);
            mainList.add(lhm);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(str);
    }
```

and my ajax call code

```
    $.ajax({
                         async: true,
                        url : "Servlet1", 
                        method : "GET",
                        dataType : "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                        success : function(tableValue) {
                         addTable(tableValue)                               
                        }                                
                    });
```

Now i have to get data from my data base and run 2 queries and have to do two different thing with there result,but doing it with creating new-new servlets now dosn't looks good
Can't i create one doGet and inside that two methods or any two methods inside servlet so that both the servlet codes can be written in oneservlet

**Note :-** i don't have knowledge on spring framework , so i want to do it with help of servlets only

anyone please guide me how can i do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could pass a distinct url parameter in your ajax calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good solution for HttpServlet classes, as you can only have one `doGet` method. A decent workaround would be adding a parameter in your url, for example `Servlet1?action=action1` and then implementing logic in your `doGet()` 
method to decide what to do based on that parameter. For example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

  String action = request.getParameter("action");

  switch(action){

  case "action1":
    doAction1(request, response); //Method with the logic of your Servlet1 class
    break;
  case "action2":
    doAction2(request, response);
    break;
  default:
    throw new ServletException("Invalid action parameter");

  }

}
```

Edit - this would be your final ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url : "Servlet1?action=action1", // Here you set the parameter
                    method : "GET",
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    success : function(tableValue) {
                     addTable(tableValue)                               
                    }                                
                });
```

Comment: can't i write userdefine method in servlet and pass that method name in my ajax url?

Comment: no, you can't since HttpServlet only allows one `doGet()` method.

Comment: so i have to make new new class like what i am doing

Comment: No, you can do it as I did in my answer, you only have one class that chooses what to do based on the "action" parameter. You just should put the logic in separate methods to make your code cleaner.

Comment: and what to write in url in ajax call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188108/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-gbandres).

Comment: hey sir you there? i a facing issue while applying your logic..whenever you ll be free please rply